# Netbeanse Can't find resourceBundles while resourceBundles in src map

Tags: java, netbeans

Normally I work with windows to program, but recently I changed to linux, Ubuntu. As you see on the picture Netbeans can't find the resourcebundles, while I have them in the /project/build/class folder and the /project/src folder.

On windows this works fine, but on Ubuntu not.

my code:

```
public Taal getTaal()
{
    return taal;
}
```

-

```
public Taal (String l)
{
    if (l.equals("nl")) this.locale = new Locale("Nederlands");
    if (l.equals("en")) this.locale = new Locale("English");
    if (l.equals("de")) this.``locale = new Locale("Deutsch");   
    resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resource",locale);       
}


public String getText(String key)
{
        return resourceBundle.getString(key);
}
```

and I call this with:

```
 while (!keuze.equals("nl") && !keuze.equals("de") && !keuze.equals("en"))
    {
        System.out.println("Voor Nederlands: typ nl");
        System.out.println("Für Deutsch, erwählt de");
        System.out.println("For English: choose en");
        keuze = s.nextLine();
    }

    dc.setTaal(keuze);
    while (juisteLetter == false)
    {
        while(nummer > 2 || nummer < 1)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(dc.getTaal().getText("aanmeldenOfRegistreren"));
                nummer = s.nextInt();
```

I saved the resourceBundles files as: resource_English.properties
and a sentence in the file is for example: 
aanmeldenOfRegistreren = Press 1 to log in, 2 to register

So, if I type "en" in the console I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resource, locale english

I don't get why netbeans can't find the resourceBundles.

Answer (score 0):

The Locale constructor transforms the language to lowercase, and is documented to accept values up to 8 characters. The language argument is supposed to be a standard 2-letter ISO code, and not some arbitrary string. Use standard codes, and everything should be fine.

BTW, you ask the user to enter those standard codes, so you're really shooting yourself in the foot by transforming them to complete uppercase language names.

Comment: still nothing, I still get the error, so I changed my resourcebundle into: en.properties and     if (l.equals("en")) this.locale = new Locale("English"); this I changed to  if (l.equals("en")) this.locale = new Locale("en"); but still an error.